# How do I change the x-axis to date format?

Tags: html, json, d3.js, visualization, linechart

How do I change the x-axis to become a date value like DD-MM-YY? My JSON data is as follow:
Is there anyway for me to change the x-axis so that it will shows DD-MM-YY for each JSON data in my file? I tried using %m/%d/%y but it does not work and I tried using %Y-%m-%d but the value that shows in my x-axis is not in %Y-%m-%d format. So, how would I be able to solve this so that my x-axis will show the date values accordingly or how would I need to change my JSON data so that it will be able to read my value?

ebolamortality.json

> [{"date":"063014","guineacase":"3","guineadeath":"5","Liberia:
>   Case":"8","Liberia: Death":"7","Sierra Leone: Case":"11","Sierra
>   Leone: Death":"2","Nigeria: Case":"0","Nigeria: Death":"0","Total Case
>   (West Africa)":"22","Total Death (West Africa)":"14","Accumulated
>   Case":"22","Accumulated Death":"14"},
>   {"date":"070214","guineacase":"0","guineadeath":"2","Liberia:
>   Case":"8","Liberia: Death":"10","Sierra Leone: Case":"13","Sierra
>   Leone: Death":"2","Nigeria: Case":"0","Nigeria: Death":"0","Total Case
>   (West Africa)":"21","Total Death (West Africa)":"14","Accumulated
>   Case":"33","Accumulated Death":"28"}]

My current webpage

```
        <html>
        <head>
        </head>

        <body>
                <div id="chart1">
                <h4> Ebola New Cases</h4>
                </div>
        </body>
        <style>
        body {
          font: 10px sans-serif;
        }

        .hover {
          text-align: center;

        }
        .axis path,
        .axis line {
          fill: none;
          stroke: #000;
          shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }

        .x.axis path {
          display: black    ;
        }

        .line {
          fill: none;
          stroke: steelblue;
          stroke-width: 1.5px;

        }   

        h4 {
          text-align: center;
        }
        .d3-tip {
          line-height: 1;
          font-weight: bold;
          padding: 12px;
          background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
          color: #fff;
          border-radius: 2px;
        }
        #chart1 {
        position: relative;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 2px;
        border-color: #CCC;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        height: 280px;
        width: 500px;
        float: left;
        }
        </style>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
            <script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
        <script>
        var margin = { top: 30, right: 70, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
                width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var tip = d3.tip()
          .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
          .offset([-10, 0])
          .html(function(d) {
            return "<p class='hover'>Male</p> </br> <strong>Age:</strong> <span style='color:white'>" + d.age + "</br><strong>Life Expectancy:</strong> <span style='color:white'>" + d.lifeexpectancymale + "%" + "</span></br><strong>World Rank:</strong> <span style='color:white'>" + d.worldrankmale;
          });

        var tip1 = d3.tip()
          .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
          .offset([-10, 0])
          .html(function(d) {
            return "<p class='hover'>Female</p> <strong>Age:</strong> <span style='color:white'>" + d.age + "</br><strong>Life Expectancy:</strong> <span style='color:white'>" + d.lifeexpectancyfemale + "%" + "</span></br><strong>World Rank:</strong> <span style='color:white'>" + d.worldrankfemale;
          });
            var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;  

            var x = d3.scale.linear()
                .range([0, width]);

            var y = d3.scale.linear()
                .range([height, 0]);


            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(x)
                .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

            var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(y)
                .orient("left").ticks(5);

            var line = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function (d) { return x(d.date); })
                .y(function (d) { return y(d.guineacase); });

            var line2 = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function (d) { return x(d.date); })
                .y(function (d) { return y(d.guineadeath); });

            var svg = d3.select("#chart1").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
              .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

            svg.call(tip).call(tip1);

            d3.json("ebolamortality.json", function (error, data) {
                data.forEach(function (d)
                {
                    d.date = parseDate(d.date.toString());
                    d.guineacase  = +d.guineacase;
                    d.guineadeath = +d.guineadeath;
                });

                x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
                  return d.date;
                }));

        /* Changed the y-axis range */      
                y.domain([d3.min(data, function (d) { return(d.guineacase)}), d3.max(data, function (d) { return(d.guineadeath)})]);

                svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "x axis")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                    .call(xAxis);

                svg.append("text")      // text label for the x axis
                  .attr("x", 155)
                  .attr("y", 235)
                  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                  .text("Date");

                svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "y axis")
                    .call(yAxis)
                  .append("text")
                    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                    .attr("y", 6)
                    .attr("dy", ".71em")
                    .style("text-anchor", "end")
                    .text("Guinea");

                svg.append("path")
                    .datum(data)
                    .attr("class", "line")
                    .style("stroke", "red")
                    .attr("d", line(data));

                svg.append("path")
                    .datum(data)
                    .attr("class", "line")
                    .style("stroke", "black")
                    .attr("d", line2(data));

                svg.selectAll('.yaxis1')
                    .data(data)
                    .enter()
                    .append('circle')
                    .attr('class', 'yaxis1')
                    .attr('cx', function (datum) {
                    return x(datum.date)
                    })
                    .attr('cy', function (datum) {
                    return y(datum.guineacase)
                    })
                    .attr('r', 3)
                    .attr('fill', 'red')
                    .on('mouseover', tip.show)
                    .on('mouseout', tip.hide);

                    svg.selectAll('.yaxis2')
                    .data(data)
                    .enter()
                    .append('circle')
                    .attr('class', 'yaxis2')
                    .attr('cx', function (datum) {
                    return x(datum.date)
                    })
                    .attr('cy', function (datum) {
                    return y(datum.guineadeath)
                    })
                    .attr('r', 3)
                    .attr('fill', 'black')
                    .on('mouseover', tip1.show)
                    .on('mouseout', tip1.hide);
            });
        </script>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following gives you the desired DD-MM-YY output format on the x-axis. The end result is smushed together, but I'm sure you can figure out how to fix that.

```
var outFormat = d3.time.format("%d-%m-%y");
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").ticks(5).tickFormat(outFormat);
```

The key is setting **tickFormat** with an appropriate **d3.time.format**.
Also your sample code's parseDate doesn't work for the JSON provided. This works.

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d%m%y").parse;
```